# Test file in hardhat, hardhat tutorial, testing token

Tags: hardhat, test

```
const { expect } = require("chai");

describe("Token contract", function () {
  it("Deployment should assign the total supply of tokens to the owner", async function () {
    const [owner] = await ethers.getSigners();

    const Token = await ethers.getContractFactory("Token");

    const hardhatToken = await Token.deploy();

    const ownerBalance = await hardhatToken.balanceOf(owner.address);
    expect(await hardhatToken.totalSupply()).to.equal(ownerBalance);
  });
});
```

please, why do they have to enclose "owner" in a close bracket?
I tried removing the square bracket, but the "owner. address" keeps returning undefine

Answer (score 1):

ethers.getSigners() returns an array

this line:

```
const [owner] = await ethers.getSigners();
```

uses brackets because it is using [destructuring](https://medium.com/@crypticmick/destructuring-arrays-objects-10e00fddd449)

> The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that
> makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from
> objects, into distinct variables.

so it is storing the first item of the array returned by getSigners in the constant **owner**

read more about destructuring [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)